# Missing constant in textbook explanation of Jeans Criterion

Tags: astrophysics

In Tsokos' *Physics for the IB Diploma: sixth edition* the Jeans Criterion is laid out as follows:

> $\frac{GM^2}{R} \ge \frac 32 NkT$

But based off all derivations of gravitational binding energy for a sphere that I've seen, there should be a factor of $\frac 35$ on the left hand side of the above inequality like so:

> $\frac{3GM^2}{5R} \ge \frac 32 NkT$

So is there something I'm missing here or did Tsokos make an error? Do the constants even matter much when considering such large masses of gas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants matter, but to calculate them accurately requires a detailed instability calculation.  So any time you see simple constants, even like 3/5, you know that a simplified conceptual calculation has been substituted for a full instability calculation.  Most sources don't bother with an accurate instability analysis because it is either beyond the scope of the source, or because the author knows that accurate calculations require idealized assumptions that are rarely true in practice (such as neglecting turbulence, magnetic fields, and rotation, etc.).  So I'd say don't worry about the missing constants, and interpret the result as an order-of-magnitude estimate.

Also, be aware that the M on the left is not independent from the N on the right, so one should probably replace N with M/m, where m is the average mass per particle, and then you can cancel one of the powers of M and get a more useful expression.  Also, the M and R are generally not independent either, because you have some prevailing density rho and you are interested in the M or R scale at which the instability sets in.  Thus one should replace R with the cube root of 3M/(4pi*rho), since it makes more sense to treat M and rho as independent than it does to treat M and R as independent.  Probably these are the next things the book does, you are only asking about a step along the way, but just to be sure this should be mentioned.